# Single threaded integration of piecewise function crashes out of memory, system monitor says it barely uses any

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, memory, crash

I've got a Mathematica script which gets out of memory errors if I evaluate it using a piecewise function, but with a constant function it's fine. Each part of the integral appears to work fine (eg I can integrate over the Wigner matrix or the exponential, but not both).

MWE:

```
Wr = 2 Pi 12500;
Ta = 0.001;
Fun1[t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Wr * 7, t < 0.125*0.001 }, {-Wr * 7, 
    0.125*0.001  <= t < 0.625*0.001 }, {Wr * 7, 
    0.625*0.001  <= t}, {0, t == 0}}]
Fun2[t_] := Wr * 3.5;
BetaRF[time_, Fn_] = 
  Integrate[Fn[ti], {ti, 0, time}, 
   Assumptions -> time \[Element] Reals];
ScaleFactor[Fn_, l_, m_, lambda_, mu_] = 
  1/Ta WignerD[{l, 0, m}, 0, 1, 0] Integrate[
    WignerD[{lambda, 0, mu}, 0, -BetaRF[t, Fn], 0] Exp[
      I * (mu  + m * Wr * t)], {t, 0, Ta}, 
    Assumptions -> Ta \[Element] Reals];

Abs[ScaleFactor[Fun2, 2, 1, 2, 2]]
```

Fun1[] is a piecewise time dependent function, which is defined over all space, Fun2[] is a constant value. BetaRF[] and ScaleFactor[] carry out some integrations and rotations.

If I pass Fun2[] (as in the MWE now), it works fine. If I pass Fun1[], it does nothing for a few sections before crashing giving the error

```
No more memory available.
Mathematica kernel has shut down.
Try quitting other applications and then retry.
```

I've seen some previous questions on here with similar out of memory errors, generally when using parallelization or with their code in a functional form where they can fit in some ClearSystemCaches[]. I don't know how I would do that in this form?

I've watched the execution in Top and the WolframKernel process doesn't appear to go above 200 MB (I've got 6 GB) so I don't think it's actually ran out of memory?

Is there something wrong with the way I've set up this function/does anyone have any idea how I could resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: I am not confident that I'm doing EXACTLY what you are doing, but if I replace all your approximate decimals with exact rationals (to perhaps provoke it to use symbolic rather than numeric methods) then I almost instantly get `(3*Cos[1/2]*Cos[1]*Sin[1/2])/(50*Pi)` with no failures and almost no memory use. Can you reproduce this? BUT if I use exactly your code above without making those changes then I almost instantly get `0.00434158` again with no failures and almost no memory use. So I'm not sure how to use your example to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I've found that if I make the changes you mentioned then it works with either Fun1[] or Fun2[]. Without them I can only get Fun2[] to work. I've found that if I replace the Integrate[] in ScaleFactor[] then it seems to work, so I think Mathematica may just be having some issues between symbolic and numeric methods but it sort of works now - thank you!